# How can I implement unidirectional synchronization of a data structure to multiple clients across web and native apps?

Tags: node.js, firebase, synchronization, open-source

We need to share a common data structure across a backend server, web clients, native iOS apps and native Android apps. The backend server is written in NodeJS and uses a Postgres database underneath.

I have considered a Firebase realtime database as it will solve all the requirements in the sense that the backend could write to the Firebase database and all clients could consume the database.

My question is if there is an open-source alternative that will work out of the box and will fit our requirements more closely than a fullblown Firebase realtime database, which will offer many features we don't need or want.

--- Here are the assumptions and requirements ----

1. The backend serves as the master so changes to the data structure can only be performed by the backend.
2. The data structure can be assumed to be a simple list of key value pairs, a simple array of objects or a full-fledged tree-structure like a json object. We can work with all solutions.
3. The data structure will be very limited in size, say, less than 100KB.
4. Any update to the data structure on the server should be propagated to all the clients that has subscribed to the data structure in near-real-time.
5. If a client is offline for a period of time, it should get updated as soon as it connects.
6. Each type of client must have a robust way of subscribing to changes in the datastructure. Hence, once the local version of the data structure is updated, at the same time it should be notified about what changed.
7. If possible the clients, when being notified about an update to the data structure, should know what "part of the data structure" has been updated.
8. We want to write as little code as possible and prefer a solution that has a server library for NodeJS and client libraries for web, native iOS and native Android.
9. The native apps cannot ask for permission for push notifications.
10. It must work on any modern browser supporting websockets or similar.

Comment: Firebase does pretty much all of that so the question is; why don't you just use Firebase Realtime Database or FireStore?

Comment: I found this comparison which seems quite relevant to my question: https://medium.com/@brenda.clark/firebase-alternative-3-open-source-ways-to-follow-e45d9347bc8c

Comment: @Jay I'm concerned about vendor lock-in, future costs getting out of hand and so forth. Also, I'm not requiring bidirectional synchronization so I have a feeling that a radically simpler solution should exist in the form of some simple libraries built around websockets or keep-alive http connections.

Comment: That article is vacuous in many statements; saying Firebase is hard to navigate, disorganized, hard to query and that your data is easily deleted isn't very accurate (deleting data in three clicks can happen to most databases) so I wouldn't read too much into it. (IMO!). vendor lock-in would be an issue with any backend database that provides an API. Parse is a good example. If an app is crafted all data is wrapped around [PFObject](http://docs.parseplatform.org/macos/guide/#objects) you're kinda locked into that without a major re-write. So, explore FB a bit and see how you like it.

Answer (score 2):

interesting question. I don't know of any open source system that will do that, I believe Firebase itself was evolved from such a system, called Parse. Now, what I can tell you is that Firebase is a solid choice, and maybe you should not discard it so quickly:

1. Firestore is the new DB system. The real-time database is going to be phased out. And firestore is superior in features.
2. Firebase is free to start, and up to a very high level, then is quite affordable.
3. It's MANAGED. I cannot stress enough the importance of this. It's not your        problem to secure or maintain the system, as it would be if you'd roll out your own solution.
4. It auto-scales, meaning, it's not your problem to plan for capacity, or purchase or roll or sync additional servers, or care for memory or disk. This is all taken care for you.
5. The "features you might not need" are HUGE time and cost savers, like managed authentication with different providers, mobile push notifications, analytics, file storage, and others.
6. It has clients for web, and mobile, so you can develop the clients you want and share the same backend.

That said, can I inquire why are you asking this? I'm very familiar with Firebase and I can probably help you out with your deployment.

Cheers

Comment: Firebase is unrelated to Parse and they have a vastly different approach, but a generally good answer.

Comment: lol, true, I had the idea that it was it's predecessor, but glad you liked my answer :P

Comment: Thx for the answer @SergioFlores. My motivation for asking the the question can be seen as a comment to my original question.

Comment: @NikolaSchou I've read the comparison you posted. First, of all, what is this overkill thing? There is no such thing. It's a flexible tool, designed for normally changing dynamics of early stage startup. Vendor lock-in ? Mmmm not really, if and when you need something different, is because you have the money to make it happen.

Comment: https://medium.com/@saft.industries/what-is-firebase-and-why-its-important-for-startups-e0a619b740c3